# switch from UIViewController to UINavigationController losing tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I need to navigate from a UIViewController to a UINavigationController, the code below does it but after switching, tab bar in bottom disappears and i get stock !

```
HomeViewController *homeList = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeList"];
UINavigationController *uc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeNav"];
uc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeList];
[self presentModalViewController:uc animated:YES];
```

The problem should be in presentModal but i don't know how to manage this.  I am new to Objective C and iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have presented it as a modal controller, the tab bar won't be shown. A modal controller by design is used to display a screen which interrupts the current work flow to present some new information, see here for how modal controllers work

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerPGforiOSLegacy/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

If you require a navigation controller, surely it would make more sense to initialise your tab controller with a navigation controller rather than a viewController, then you can move from one screen to the next using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someController animated:YES];
```

Comment: i use this `UINavigationController *uc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeNav"];[self.navigationController pushViewController:uc animated:YES];` and it wont work.  i can't change the UINavigationController.